# Do Fortnite V-Bucks Purchases Save on All Platforms?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

So I'm thinking of buying some V-Bucks on Fortnite, Battle Royale mobile. Do the purchases save cross platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**:

At some point in time since this answer was originally written (possibly around 2022?), Epic Games created a "Shared Wallet" system.  The updated [FAQ page](https://www.fortnite.com/faq) now says:

> Are my V-Bucks bound to the platform I purchase/redeem them on?
>
> V-Bucks purchased/redeemed on one platform are available on all other
> platforms that support Fortnite Shared Wallet: PlayStation, Xbox, PC,
> Android, and cloud gaming services.
>
> V-Bucks purchased/redeemed on Nintendo Switch can only be spent on
> that platform and will not appear if you log in on a different
> platform.
>
> V-Bucks unlocked through the Battle Pass, Quest Packs, or earned in
> Save the World can be seen and spent across all platforms. All items
> acquired with V-Bucks, gameplay, rewards or giveaways, and more can be
> accessed across all platforms as well.

So now, it seems if you *buy* V-Bucks, they are shared across everything **except** Nintendo Switch.  However, any V-Bucks you *earn* are shared across **all plaforms**.  It also seems anything you purchase with the V-Bucks are shared across platforms as well.

---

**Original Answer**:

**TL;DR**: If you buy V-Bucks on PC or mobile, they are shared if you have your Epic account linked. If you buy them on PS4, Nintendo Switch, or Xbox One they aren't shared. The items you buy with them are shared if you have your accounts linked to your Epic ID. Any earned V-Bucks from playing are shared across platforms.

Interesting enough, V-Bucks have some odd rules.  The [official FAQ page](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/faq) (Billing section) states:

> Purchased V-Bucks are shared between PC and mobile if you've linked your account with your Epic ID. However, V-Bucks purchased on PlayStation 4, Xbox One, or Switch are not shared between other platforms.

[According to a post made by Epic Games](https://epicgames.helpshift.com/a/fortnite/?s=ps4-support&f=why-don-t-all-of-my-v-bucks-transfer-across-platforms&p=all) in regards to PS4 and Nintendo Switch:

> V-Bucks purchased on Nintendo Switch and PlayStation 4 are only available on the platform they are purchased on. All other V-Bucks, are available across platform.

So it looks like any V-Bucks you buy on a console are only for that console. Any that you earn from actually playing the game are cross platform.  The article states that this restriction applies only to the V-Bucks themselves. The **items you purchase** with them **are** cross platform (if you have your account linked to your Epic ID like mentioned above):

> The restrictions outlined above apply to V-bucks only.  Any content purchased with your V-bucks will be available across platforms.