# V-bucks purchased on PC not showing on Switch

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I have purchased v-bucks on the PC but they are not showing on my Switch.

Both the answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/331898/201223) and the [FAQs it quotes](https://www.epicgames.com/help/en-US/fortnite-c75/billing-support-c121/why-don-t-all-of-my-vbucks-transfer-across-platforms-a3305) suggest I should not expect it to work the other way around (that is, v-bucks bought on the Switch won’t appear on the PC) but they both imply it should work the way around I’m doing it:

> If you buy V-Bucks on PC or mobile, they are shared if you have your
> Epic account linked.

> V-Bucks purchased on Nintendo Switch, Xbox One, and PlayStation 4 are only available on the platform they are purchased on. All other V-Bucks, are available across platform.

Although the example the FAQ page uses does seem to contradict this:

> Example 1:1000 V-Bucks purchased on PC.
>
> ◦ PC will display 1000 V-Bucks available.
> ◦ PS4 will display 0 V-Bucks available.

Which is correct, or have the rules changed since these were written?