# Can Fortnite Vbucks cards be used on any console?

Tags: nintendo-switch, fortnite-battle-royale, ps5

My son has multiple consoles linked to his Fortnite account. I just bought him a Vbucks card from Walmart, does it matter what console I pick? If I click Nintendo Switch, can he spend them on the Playstation?

Comment: I _think_ this is a dupe of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/331898/do-fortnite-v-bucks-purchases-save-on-all-platforms but the linked question seems to be about the items purchased rather than specifically V-Bucks so not sure.  I think they are similar enough however.

Answer (score 10):

It's a little bit complicated.

Fortnite has a [shared wallet system,](https://fortnite.com/news/v-bucks-purchased-on-playstation-join-fortnite-shared-wallet) in which redeeming V-bucks on particular platforms allows them to be spent on other platforms. Currently, almost all platforms that currently support Fortnite (except Nintendo Switch) participate in this shared wallet system.

This means that if you redeem the V-bucks card on your PlayStation, you'll also be able to spend those V-bucks on Xbox, PC, Android and cloud gaming services, but *not* on Switch. Likewise, if you redeem the V-bucks card on your Switch, you'll *only* be able to spend those V-bucks on your Switch.

However, as long as each console is linked to the same Epic Games account, you can spend V-bucks on any platform, and anything you buy will still be available across all supported platforms.

It's worth noting that the shared wallet system only applies to purchased V-bucks. V-bucks earned through gameplay, such as through the Battle Pass, quest packs, and Save The World mode can be spent across all platforms.

Comment: Good answer - I've actually answer this [same question (or at least very similar)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/331898/do-fortnite-v-bucks-purchases-save-on-all-platforms) before previously, but you've brought forth new information that I've since updated my answer with.